# Can i use cordova-plugin-ionic-webview without using ionic?

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

im getting the new warning from apple warning "New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. "

currently im using framework7 core and cordova.

If so, im still doing something wrong, because im getting the same error from them, can you help?

Comment: Your question needs more claification, the title is somwthing and the content is describing another thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Add plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, preferably the latest version 1.2.1

2.Add the following preferences in your config.xml for IOS.

```html
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />

    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>

    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple is trying to abandon UIWebview and force user to use WKWebview instead. From **April 2020**, **no new iOS app** using UIWebview can be submitted to Appstore, and from **Dec 2020, no iOS app update** using UIWebview can be submitted.

If you are using ionic, then no need to worry because ionic use WKW

If you are using Cordova only, the team is trying to upgrade their core to WKW, however, this will take some time. In that mean time, a hotfix is to install `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`.

More info can be read here :https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/